# Oracle Http Server as proxy for Openshiftroute

Tags: openshift, weblogic12c, oam, oracle-http-server

We have oracle products like OAM, OIG and SOA. We are using Routes to access these externally. The route urls are accessible but as a requirement we need to have a Oracle HTTP server as proxy in front of OAM and other products.

We want below configuration:

browser --> OHS --> Route --> OAM PODS (on openshift)

When we installed OHS and redirected it to openshift route,

`<VirtualHost xx.xx.xx.xx:xxxx>     ServerName http://xx.xx.xx.xx:xxxx     ServerAdmin you@your.address     RewriteEngine On     RewriteOptions inherit     UseCanonicalName On     RequestHeader set "X-Forwarded-Host" "xx.xx.xx.xx:xxxx"     LimitRequestFieldSize 655362 LoadModule weblogic_module   "${PRODUCT_HOME}/modules/mod_wl_ohs.so" <IfModule weblogic_module> #OAM Entries <Location /console>     WLSRequest ON     DynamicServerList OFF     WLCookieName OAMJSESSIONID     WebLogicCluster xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.apps.dev-rdc-01.xxxxxx.xxxxx.xxxxx.eg:80 </Location> </IfModule> </VirtualHost>`

we get bridge fail error -

Failure of Web Server bridge-
No backend server available for connection: timed out after 10 seconds or idempotent set to OFF or method not idempotent.

Can OHS be used as proxy for route urls? If yes, how can it be done?

Comment: oam is Oracle Access manager, OHS is Oracle Https Server. OpenShift route is edge/termination

Answer (score 0):

What's `OHS` and `OAM`? It would be nice when you explain or at least add the link to the abbreviation as not everybody know this abbreviation.

Which Type of OpenShift route do you use (edge, passthrough or re-encrypt)?
Which Version of OpenShift do you use?

Maybe you should use [passthrough](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.14/networking/routes/secured-routes.html#nw-ingress-creating-a-passthrough-route_secured-routes) in the first step to see if the setup works in general. The passthrough Route make "just" a tcp forwarding and the whole TLS Handling is done from the `O*` components.

Comment: oam is Oracle Access manager, OHS is Oracle Https Server. OpenShift route is edge/termination. Version of Opensift is 4.12.

Comment: as suggested try passthrough Route and see if this works. I passthrough Route works try to find the missing http headers in case you still want to use edge termination